# Angular: how to close a sidenav with the BACK button

Tags: angularjs, mobile, history

Developping an angular application with a left sidenav, most of our users find it usual to close this sidenav when they press the BACK button of their mobile, or with a left SWIPE.

For the left swipe, this is OK (with md-swipe-right=...). However I find nothing about using the BACK button. Is there a nice way to do it? How should the location changed event be catched and prevented (or something like that)?

Comment: You can't intercept the back browser event and change the behavior! The only way is to generate route/state navigation when left sidenav is opened, then the back browser action will restore the prev history

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how to generate a state? Except using the JS history API, I can't find any built-in method to do it

Comment: Have you any solution?

Comment: No, I don't work on it anymore

Answer (score 3):

For future reference:

One method I've found was pushing a fake state to the navigator's history when opening the sidenav and removing it in case the back button wasn't pushed but instead it was closed regularly. if the back button is pushed then the fake state will automatically go away with the back() event that fires when the button was pushed.

then listening to the back button event called 'popstate' with a directive on the sidenav you can play with the whole thing as you wish.

example:

directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[CatchMobileBackEvent]'
})
...
  sidebar: MatSidenav;

@Input('sidenavRef') set sidenavRef(sidenav: MatSidenav) { // get the sidebar ref
    this.sidebar = sidenav;
  }

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event']) onMobileBack(e) { // when back button pushed close sidenav (and it stays on the same page because the current history state is fake)
        this.sidebar.close();
  }
@HostListener('closed', ['$event']) checkIfClosedFromButton(e) { // listen to sidebar's closed event
      if (history.state === 'sidebarOpened') { // it means the sidebar was closed not from the mobile back button
        history.back(); // remove the fake history state
      }
  }
@HostListener('opened', ['$event']) pushFakeHistoryWhenOpened(e) { // listen to sidebar's opened event
    if (this.isSmartphone$.getValue()) {
      history.pushState('sidebarOpened', 'sidebarOpened'); // for mobile back button
    }
  }
```

and in the template:

```
 <mat-sidenav
     #sideNavMenu // declare the sidebar as a template variable so you can pass it to the directive
     CatchMobileBackEvent // put the directive on the sidebar you want to control
     [sidenavRef]="sideNavMenu"> // pass the sidebar ref to the directive
```